# How to connect new elements, generated after the page rendering, to events in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Jquery to add some `<select>` into a `<div>`.

This `<select>` should trigger an event `change()` having a class assigned to it (like: `<select class="trigger">` -> `$(.trigger).change(...)` )

The problem is that, if I put this in plain HTML, it works.
But the `<select>` I add with Jquery don't work.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row align-center" id="plus">
    <div class="small-2 columns">
        <img src="img/plus.png" onclick="add_Filter()"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function add_Filter(){
$("#plus").before('<div class="row align-center"> \
    <div class="small-6 column"> \
        <select name="attr" class="trigger"> \
            <option value=""></option> \
            <option value="One">One</option> \
            <option value="Two">Two</option> \
            <option value="Three">Three</option> \
        </select> \
    </div> \
</div>');

$(".trigger").change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Note: I could add an "onchange()" attribute to the `<select>` but I need the **this** variable.

Comment: search for Event Delegation in jquery

Comment: use `$(document).on("change",".trigger",function() {` instead of `$(".trigger").change(function() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to apply an event to markup that's loaded dynamically you will need to attach it to an element that's present so the event bubbling can find your new element.

```
$('body').on('change', '.trigger', function() {
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

EDIT

An explanation of why/how this works, when an event fires on an element it bubbles up the DOM tree, effectively triggering the event on all of it's parent elements as well. You can't bind an event to an element that doesn't exist in the DOM, however you can bind it to one of it's parent elements (as long as they exist in the DOM) that it's event bubbles up to.

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation

Comment: I haven't understand what's event bubbling... It works! But i need some explaination on what going on there!

Comment: @MarkWuji Have a read of this https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation

Comment: Dontfeedthecode's answer is completely correct. Using jquery you should not forget that you are still using javascript. And what does javascript do concerning events? Right, it's using attached event handlers. Meaning on page load you can attach some events on actions being done by html objects. But you cannot bind an event to a non-existing element. Therefor you need to bind the event to the parent element of the dynamically added html element.
+1 @Dontfeedthecode

Comment: Oh ok, so: Jquery attaches the events on the HTML elements at the very start, so if i add an element later with this method it will not work.
But if i attach the element on the parent node it works like an "event listener" so that every element with those attributes will be triggered as well. Genius! I still don't understand the Jquery syntax in this but i will look for it later, thanks ^^

Comment: Yes, event attaching is done at page load. The syntax is easy:
$('body') is the body DOM-element;
.on is the event trigger;
'change' is the event to be listened for;
'.trigger' is the selector. Meaning all object having the class 'trigger' will be called;
function(){..} is the function to be executed.

Comment: So what could happen if i put like a <div id=select-container> and then $(#select-container).on(etc...), it will work, right?
And if i put it on every div (fantasy) EVERY DIV will have this thing (resource consuming, like putting in on body actually).
Ok, i understand the question reallly well thank you all!

Comment: @MarkWuji That will work indeed, it doesnt have to use body as the selector - you can use the closest parent element as long as it's in the DOM when the page is loaded so you're container would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding the elements dynamically the events are not binded to them. So you have to bind the events to the newly added element or use event delegation to trigger events on dynamically added elements. So here are the two solutions.

**1)** While inserting the new element itself bind the change event and then insert before the `#plus` element.

```
  function add_Filter(){
    $("#plus").before($('<div class="row align-center"> \
        <div class="small-6 column"> \
            <select name="attr" class="trigger"> \
                <option value=""></option> \
                <option value="One">One</option> \
                <option value="Two">Two</option> \
                <option value="Three">Three</option> \
            </select> \
        </div> \
    </div>').find('.trigger').change(function() { // add event to this newly adding element. 
      alert($(this).val());
    }));              
}
```

Note the changes.

```
 function add_Filter(){
        $("#plus").before($('...').find('.trigger').change(function() { 
          alert($(this).val());
        }));              
    }
```

**2)** Use [**event delegation (event propogattion)**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation).

```
$('body').on('change', '.trigger', function() {
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: I can't really understand the first solution, but +1 for answering and giving me a new method to study thank you ^^

Comment: First method build a jquery object and then navigate to find the select tag and then apply the event handlers, then this entire stuff is inserted before the #plus element